# Possible arbitrary file inclusion

Tags: error, security

This is the 3rd time I have seen this on a relatively fresh install of Magento. The only place that the email `Hello@example.com` exists is in:

```
System > Configuration > Contacts > Email Options
```

system.log:

```
2015-02-03T20:12:11+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: include(Hello@example.com.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory  in  /chroot/data/******/******/html/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 94
2015-02-03T20:12:11+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: include(): Failed opening 'Hello@example.com.php' for inclusion (include_path='/chroot/data/******/******/html/app/code/local:/chroot/data/******/******/html/app/code/community:/chroot/data/******/******/html/app/code/core:/chroot/data/******/******/html/lib:.:/usr/share/pear:/usr/share/php')  in /chroot/data/******/******/html/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 94
2015-02-03T20:12:11+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: include(Hello.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory  in /chroot/data/******/******/html/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 94
2015-02-03T20:12:11+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: include(): Failed opening 'Hello.php' for inclusion (include_path='/chroot/data/*******/******/html/app/code/local:/chroot/data/*******/******/html/app/code/community:/chroot/data/*******/******/html/app/code/core:/chroot/data/*******/******/html/lib:.:/usr/share/pear:/usr/share/php')  in /chroot/data/*******/******/html/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 94
```

I'm not sure why the Autoload would be trying to include a file from a config value.

**EDIT:**

References to "recipient_email":

```
$ grep -rnw ./ -e "recipient_email"
./public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Contacts/controllers/IndexController.php:37:    const XML_PATH_EMAIL_RECIPIENT  = 'contacts/email/recipient_email';
./public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Contacts/etc/config.xml:98:                <recipient_email><![CDATA[hello@example.com]]></recipient_email>
./public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Contacts/etc/system.xml:67:                        <recipient_email translate="label">
./public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Contacts/etc/system.xml:75:                        </recipient_email>
./public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Email/Queue.php:81:                array('recipient_email', 'recipient_name', 'email_type')
./public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Email/Queue.php:94:                $oldEmails[$recipient['recipient_email']] = array(
./public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Email/Queue.php:95:                    $recipient['recipient_email'], $recipient['recipient_name'], $recipient['email_type']
./public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Email/Queue.php:129:            ->from($this->getTable('core/email_recipients'), array('recipient_email', 'recipient_name', 'email_type'))
./public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Email/Queue.php:136:                    $recipient['recipient_email'],
./public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Email/Queue.php:169:                         'recipient_email' => $email,
./public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/sql/core_setup/upgrade-1.6.0.5-1.6.0.6.php:87:    ->addColumn('recipient_email', Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_TEXT, 128, array(
./public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/sql/core_setup/upgrade-1.6.0.5-1.6.0.6.php:97:    ->addIndex($installer->getIdxName('core/email_recipients', array('recipient_email')),
./public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/sql/core_setup/upgrade-1.6.0.5-1.6.0.6.php:98:        array('recipient_email'))
./public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/sql/core_setup/upgrade-1.6.0.5-1.6.0.6.php:104:            array('message_id', 'recipient_email', 'email_type'),
./public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/sql/core_setup/upgrade-1.6.0.5-1.6.0.6.php:107:        array('message_id', 'recipient_email', 'email_type'),
./public_html/var/*******_magento.sql:4287:  `recipient_email` varchar(128) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Recipient Email',
./public_html/var/*******_magento.sql:4291:  UNIQUE KEY `*******` (`message_id`,`recipient_email`,`email_type`),
./public_html/var/*******_magento.sql:4292:  KEY `IDX_CORE_EMAIL_QUEUE_RECIPIENTS_RECIPIENT_EMAIL` (`recipient_email`),
```

References to "XML_PATH_EMAIL_RECIPIENT":

```
$ grep -rnw ./ -e "XML_PATH_EMAIL_RECIPIENT"
./app/code/core/Mage/Contacts/controllers/IndexController.php:37:    const XML_PATH_EMAIL_RECIPIENT  = 'contacts/email/recipient_email';
./app/code/core/Mage/Contacts/controllers/IndexController.php:101:                        Mage::getStoreConfig(self::XML_PATH_EMAIL_RECIPIENT),
```

Comment: Can you search your file system for all files which contain `recipient_email` and see if maybe you have some module assigning that config value to a variable, and then passing it to `Mage::getModel` or some craziness?

Comment: I updated the original post with the requested information.

Comment: What version of php are you running on the server?

Comment: PHP version 5.3.24

Comment: That config var gets the constant `XML_PATH_EMAIL_RECIPIENT`. Can you check where that is being used?

Comment: There is no external reference to that constant. Updating original post with reference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In `/lib/Varien/Autoload.php` above line 94, add the following:

```
if (strstr($classFile, '@')) {
    try {
        Mage::log(var_export(debug_backtrace(DEBUG_BACKTRACE_IGNORE_ARGS), true), null, 'system.log', true);
    } catch (Exception $e) {}
}
```

Then hit any page known to cause to Warning in your logs. Then go to `/var/log/system.log` and look for a debug stack trace. It will start with this:

```
  0 => 
  array (
    'function' => 'autoload',
    'class' => 'Varien_Autoload',
    'type' => '->',
  ),
```

From there, you should see what file and method is causing an autoload of this non-existent class.

**When you're done, revert Autoload.php**

Comment: Thanks. I found the issue. It is in a widely used extension and appears to be exploitable. I'm contacting the extension developer to disclose the vulnerability. In short, it has to do with improper use of the `is_subclass_of` method.